# Codeigniter Form Validation is_unique seems to be adding subdomain to the tablename

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm kind of perplexed with this issue.  My code is really different so I expected different results.  But I'm running form validations and trying to call the is_unique function.  But it appears that it's adding my subdomain to the table name in the query. And for the life of me i can't figure out why.

I have a library class that sets up the controls it requires here

```
protected function settablecolumnattributes(){
    $this->addcolumnattributes(
        array(
            "name" => "user_login",
            "type" => "VARCHAR",
            "length" => "255",
            "default" => "NULL",
            "collation" => "",
            "attributes" => "",
            "null" => "",
            "index" => "",
            "autoincrement" => "",
            "comments" => "",
            "width" => "",
            "sortable" => "true",
            "control" => array(
                "type" => "textbox",
                "label" => "User Login",
                "id" => "",
                "class" => "",
                "placeholder" => "Enter a Username",
                "validations" => "required|is_unique[blah.user_login]"
            ),
            "visible_on_form" => true,
            "visible_on_table" => true
        )
    );
}
```

then i am collecting all of the control validations here and outputting them.

```
public function set_object_form_validations(){
    $fields = $this->getcolumnattributes();

    foreach( $fields as $field ):
        $visible_on_form = property_exists( $field, "visible_on_form" );
        if( $visible_on_form !== false ):
            if( $field->visible_on_form !== true ):
                continue;
            endif;
        endif;
            $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules($field->name, $field->control['label'], $field->control['validations']);
    endforeach;
}
```

now when the validations encounters the `is_unique` i get this error

```
Error Number: 1146
Table '12385468.demo_blah' doesn't exist
SELECT * FROM `demo_blah` WHERE `user_login` = 'joe' LIMIT 1
Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
Line Number: 1125
```

the testing url i am using is like this `demo.example.com/admin/users/add`

I've went into the form validations file and tried to trace this issue back but it just keeps going deeper and deeper into the CI functions.  Every spot that `$table` is present just says `blah`, but you can see in the query it says `demo_blah`.  I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after drilling through all of the codeigniter functions. Turns out there was a database prefix set inside `config.php = $config['dbprefix']`.  I thought it was the subdomain originally because it said demo.  but the prefix was set to demo also.  There was actually nothing wrong with the query just my settings.